# Can't run JUnit test with Spring

Tags: spring, junit

I have a test class looking like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class myTests {

    @Autowired
    private MyComponent myComponent;

    @Test
    public void test1() { ... }
}
```

I get an initialization error and an exception:

```
java.lang.Exception: No tests found matching...
```

Comment: What is Test import, how do you run exactly?

Comment: I think you don't have enough content for a [mcve]. Beyond that, did you pick a good tutorial about this topic? If so, it might be helpful to link to the guide you are following ...

Comment: The Test import is 'org.junit.Test'

Comment: what version of JUnit do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your imports; for your code to work in the way you intend it to, your imports should include:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
```

but depending on how your IDE is configured you can sometimes end up with a different version of junit by default which doesn't play nicely with Spring Boot.

If the above imports don't work for you you may need to add the following maven dependency to your pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```